# GridBagLayout Weights and Overlapping Components

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Suppose I have a `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout` like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|      |               |               |      |   
|      |Left JLabel 1  | Right JLabel 1|      |   
|      |               |               |      |   
|-glue-|Left JLabel 2  | Right JLabel 2|-glue-|
|      |               |               |      |   
|      |         Bottom JLabel         |      |   
|      |               |               |      |   
|                vertical glue                |   
-----------------------------------------------
```

The left/right labels each span 1 row and 1 column, while the bottom label spans 1 row and 2 columns. The horizontal glues on both sides span 3 rows and 1 column each. The vertical glue at the bottom spans 1 row and 4 columns.

Each of the labels has a `weighty` of `1.0`. Further, the glues on both sides also have a `weighty` of `1.0`. The vertical glue has a `weighty` of `1.5`. Currently, when I resize the panel in the `y`-direction, the vertical glue gets approximately 3/5ths of the available space and the entire upper portion gets approximately 2/5ths of the available space.

My question is, how does the weighting work when the glue overlaps (when viewed from the `y`-resize perspective) with the buttons? Without the glue, the total weight of the buttons would have been `3.0`: this is a completely different resizing scenario! How is the weight actually calculated (highest, average, 'seen from a resize perspective', ?) and used?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the calculation is rather complex so who knows exactly what is happening.

I would guess you are getting something like:

1. The "vertical glue" is considered one row of data so it gets 1.5.
2. The "glue" components are consider another row of data so they get 1.0.
3. Then within the "glue" components you have 3 more rows of data and they each get .33 of the space allocated to the "glue" components.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but "who knows exactly what is happening": who does, indeed? Are there any Java language developers on SO ? :)

Also, the example I've given in my question is quite simple, but what if the glue and buttons only partially overlap? What if there are multiple columns that overlap to different degrees?

Comment: `but what if the glue and buttons only partially overlap?` - that is were it would get even more complicated. I always suggest using nested panels with appropriate layout manger instead of trying to force a layout with a single layout manager.